# Encode URL-encoded string into JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, url-encoding

I have a query string with URL-encoded symbols:

```
$wm_string = "LMI_MODE=1&LMI_PAYMENT_DESC=%CF%EE%E6%E5%F0%F2%E2%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5+Plan+Z";
```

I need to convert it into JSON with PHP, but `json_encode` returns an empty string.

Here is my code in PHP:

```
parse_str($wm_string, $_REQUEST);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
echo "JSON:".json_encode($_REQUEST);
```

Here is the result:

```
array(1) { ["LMI_MODE"]=> string(46) "1?LMI_PAYMENT_DESC=Пожертвование Plan Z Online" } JSON:
```

What should I do?

UPDATE:

The expected result is:

```
{ 
    "LMI_MODE":1,
    "LMI_PAYMENT_DESC":"Пожертвование Plan Z Online" 
}
```

UPDATE2:
The encoding is windows-1251, while `json_encode` seems to be expecting UTF-8. Is there a way to tell `json_encode` which encoding it should use while parsing?

Comment: Encode the url on the javascript side instead of the php side. I use json encode a lot and regularly send urls. Never bothered to encode them first as it doesn't make sense in my use case. You could probably find a way around it as well.

Comment: I can't because it is done by the external payment system.

Comment: check json_last_error(). There's no way it should fail to encode such a simple array.

Comment: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encodedю
The form posts in Windows 1251.

Comment: Ah ok. If it's a 3rd party posting in the wrong encoding then yes you need to iconv everything. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Since `json_encode` does work with UTF-8 only, and the text is in windows-1251, it should be converted from that encoding to UTF-8.

```
$wm_string = "LMI_MODE=1&LMI_PAYMENT_DESC=%CF%EE%E6%E5%F0%F2%E2%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5+Plan+Z+Online";
$wm_string = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $wm_string);
parse_str(urldecode($wm_string), $result);
echo "JSON:".json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Output:

```
JSON:{"LMI_MODE":"1","LMI_PAYMENT_DESC":"Пожертвование Plan Z Online"}
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing.  Why are you saving back to the $_REQUEST variable?  There is also no need to urldecode so many times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$wm_string = "LMI_MODE=1LMI_PAYMENT_DESC=%CF%EE%E6%E5%F0%F2%E2%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5+Plan+Z";
$wm_string = (parse_url(urldecode($wm_string)));
$wm_string = json_encode(urlencode($wm_string['path']));
echo "JSON: " . $wm_string;
```

Result:

```
JSON: "LMI_MODE%3D1LMI_PAYMENT_DESC%3D%CF%EE%E6%E5%F0%F2%E2%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5+Plan+Z"
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.
I have added the expected result of json_encode output in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is similar to the other two answers, but just wanted to point out that you don't need to and in fact [shouldn't be using urldecode with parse_url](https://secure.php.net/parse_str#usernotes).  In a simpler approach you could parse the url string and convert the windows-1251 variable to utf8 like this.

```
<?php

$wm_string = "LMI_MODE=1&LMI_PAYMENT_DESC=%CF%EE%E6%E5%F0%F2%E2%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5+Plan+Z+Online";

//Parse the url string
parse_str($wm_string, $args);

//Convert payment description to utf8
$args['LMI_PAYMENT_DESC'] = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $args['LMI_PAYMENT_DESC']);

echo "JSON: " . json_encode($args, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

//JSON: {"LMI_MODE":"1","LMI_PAYMENT_DESC":"Пожертвование Plan Z Online"}
```

Comment: What if there was another variable needing conversion? Then should we `iconv` it as well?
Originally I didn't know what to expect to see in $_POST and tried to save it to a file via json_encode. 
That turned out to be a very bad idea and I should've used `var_export` instead, but this is another story.

Comment: Are you reading from $_POST? So is your $wm_string variable just for convenience to ask the question? You don't even need parse_str in that case since you're not parsing a string. But yes you could loop all items or take a look at fixing the issue at source which is probably the character encoding on your page/form.